# How to 'Exclude folder from search' using right-click menu in VS Code 1.73?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VS Code 1.73.1 but I can't see the new 'Exclude folder from search' right-click option when clicking on a search result. I guess I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas please?

Comment: Just realized that the results must be in Tree View to see this option.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the results must be in Tree View to see this option.